# Upload image from gallery in android

Tags: android

I want to get an image from a gallery to show in imageview. Intent returned the path as "Content" in Sony mobile. I can get it using this code.

```
Uri image=data.getData();
```

But when I am using a Samsung mobile, intent returned this.

```
Intent { act=file:///mnt/sdcard/Pictures/Education%20App/IMG_20140513_160840.jpg (has extras) }
```

I used same code to get the URI, but the returned value is null. I don't know how to get this Uri.

Answer (score 0):

I have demonstrate to Both the case

1) capture Photo from camera

2) Take a photo from gallary

**Try this is working like charm with me**

```
private String selectedImagePath = "";
    final private int PICK_IMAGE = 1;
    final private int CAPTURE_IMAGE = 2;

public Uri setImageUri() {
        // Store image in dcim
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DCIM/", "image" + new Date().getTime() + ".png");
        Uri imgUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        this.imgPath = file.getAbsolutePath();
        return imgUri;
    }


    public String getImagePath() {
        return imgPath;
    }

btnGallery.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, ""), PICK_IMAGE);

            }
        });

        btnCapture.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, setImageUri());
                startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE);
            }
        });

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) {
                selectedImagePath = getAbsolutePath(data.getData());
                imgUser.setImageBitmap(decodeFile(selectedImagePath));
            } else if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE) {
                selectedImagePath = getImagePath();
                imgUser.setImageBitmap(decodeFile(selectedImagePath));
            } else {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            }
        }

    }


public Bitmap decodeFile(String path) {
        try {
            // Decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, o);
            // The new size we want to scale to
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;

            // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            int scale = 1;
            while (o.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE && o.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE)
                scale *= 2;

            // Decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, o2);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }

public String getAbsolutePath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaColumns.DATA };
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaColumns.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        } else
            return null;
    }
```